# Display countdown with Moment.js by getting the difference in milliseconds between two dates - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, react-compound-timer

I am building a page that having a specific expiration duration calculated according the page max allowed days and page when first time opened from that user.

There is two values that page will depend on for calculating the remaining time till page expire:-

1. durationInDaysFromApi: the max allowed day to open the page.
2. timestampFromApi: the time when the user first opened the page.

The steps i am trying to do in code to get the milliseconds value and use it in count down timer:-

1. Convert the timezone of timestamp fetched from api to "Asia/Kuwait".

> var createdAt = moment.tz(timestampFromApi, "Asia/Kuwait");

2. Add the x number of days to the timestampFromApi:-

> var added = createdAt.clone().add(durationInDaysFromApi, "days");

3. Get the difference between two dates to calculate the remaining time
   till page access expire to that user:-

> const diffInMilliseconds = added.diff(createdAt);

So the final equation will look like this (timeRemainedToExpireInMillisecondForTheCounter = added - createdAt)

Here is sample code if what i am trying to do:-

```
  const timestampFromApi = "2020-08-29 04:39:14";
  const durationInDaysFromApi = 7;
  var createdAt = moment.tz(timestampFromApi, "Asia/Kuwait");
  var added = createdAt.clone().add(durationInDaysFromApi, "days");
      added = moment.tz(added, "Asia/Kuwait");
  const diffInMilliseconds = added.diff(createdAt);
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sun-61j58?file=/src/App.js)

The problem with my code that it always return milliseconds value equal to 7 days, how can i fix it to return the milliseconds between two dates to get the remaining time for page to expire?

Comment: i think it's because the `durationInDaysFromApi` fixed with 7

Comment: Yes @BoussadjraBrahim suggest is correct. You want difference between `timestampFromApi` and `durationInDaysFromApi` right?

Comment: Yes it seems correct. it is taking 7 days because it's fixed for `durationInDaysFromApi`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `add` the 7 `days` and then get that time and compare that `datetime` with your `current` datetime (Kuwait) and get `difference` in `milliseconds` using `.diff`  function which you will use you to return to your `React` Counter
`plugin`

The reason it was always showing 7 days remaining were that you are always adding the days to your `timestampFromApi` but not comparing with current date time.

**Live Sandbox Demo:**

[image: Moment JS Countdown]

**Live SO Demo:** (Showing milliseconds remaining)

```js
const dateFromApi = "2020-08-29 16:37:58";
const createdAt = moment.tz(dateFromApi, "Asia/Kuwait");
const added = createdAt.clone().add(7, "days");
const now = moment.tz("Asia/Kuwait"); //now time kuwait
const duration = added.diff(now, "milliseconds"); //get diff in millinseconds
console.log(duration)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine. It continuously shows 7 days because the timer component is not updating when you change the `durationInDaysFromApi`  value. you just need to use `UseEffect` or `componentDidMount` to update your timer component when the `durationInDaysFromApi`  value gets changed.